# Three20 URLNavigation: Disabling view persistence for some controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I generally like the View Persistor in the Three20 URLNavigation, however, I would like to exclude a few Controllers so they can't be the the first controller to show when the app loads. how can i do that?

Comment: You may have better luck asking this at: http://three20.stackexchange.com/ since the guy taking over the three20 code moderates that forum

Comment: thanks, i thought that if you tag it with three20 it shows up there too...but it seems to be a different plattform altogether.

Answer (score 2):

In the viewController that should not be persisted, just overwrite persistView: and return NO. That should do the trick.

```
- (BOOL)persistView:(NSMutableDictionary*)state {
  return NO;
}
```

see TTAlertViewController, TTActionSheetController